# Java IOException invalid constant type

Tags: java, java-8

I have installed `jdk1.8.0_181` version and while am bringing my application am getting following logs in the console.

Am not user why am getting these logs is that related to version problem ? How to fix this issues. ?

Please find my logs below.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15 at 142
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1044)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:984)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:125)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:770)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:114)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:191)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:98)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:84)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:711)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:688)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCastExpr(TypeChecker.java:547)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCastExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:104)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CastExpr.accept(CastExpr.java:55)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atVariableAssign(TypeChecker.java:249)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atAssignExpr(TypeChecker.java:218)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.AssignExpr.accept(AssignExpr.java:39)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atForStmnt(CodeGen.java:480)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:359)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:391)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:355)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodBody(CodeGen.java:292)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodDecl(CodeGen.java:274)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.MethodDecl.accept(MethodDecl.java:44)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileMethod(Javac.java:169)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compile(Javac.java:95)
    at javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:74)
    at javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:45)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.JavassistCompilerStrategy.compileClass(JavassistCompilerStrategy.java:251)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.SourceCodeContext.compileClass(SourceCodeContext.java:249)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.SourceCodeContext.getInstance(SourceCodeContext.java:266)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:75)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.buildMapper(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1360)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.build(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1195)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.getMapperFacade(DefaultMapperFactory.java:859)
```

Please find the below code :

```
 public void merge(Program that) {
    getMapper().map(that, this);   // Getting error on this line.
    if (that.flatPercentageDiscount == null) this.flatPercentageDiscount = null;
  }
```